# automplete doesn´t set color when select displayed values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I do have an autocomplete jQuery-ui that displays the company names and everything works fine, but  my problem is when the users hover the mouse (or keyboard arrow) to select a value from the autocomplete field because it doesn´t shows any color, it just shows a non-color rectangle and what I want is as the users hovers the differents values displayed it shows a color over the value, something like this.

[image]

this is my jQuery code, the first two are jQuery libraries, those are missing the script tag because the forum don´t let them to appear and the third one is a link tag.

```
src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js">
rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" 

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#SearchString").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action(actionName: "autocompletar", controllerName: "Borrar")',
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { prefix: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { value: item.np, label: item.empresa };
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item) {
                    $("#numeroPatronal").val(ui.item.value);
                    $("#SearchString").val(ui.item.label);
                }
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;

            },
                change: function(event, ui) {
                    //$("#numeroPatronal").val(ui.item==="" ? ui.item.value : "");
                    if (!ui.item) {
                        $("#numeroPatronal").val("");

                    } else {
                        $("#numeroPatronal").val(ui.item.value);
                    }
                },
        });
            });
        });
    });
```

and this is the css on my page

```
.ui-autocomplete
    {
        /*position:inherit;*/
        cursor: default;
        height: 500px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.ui-menu-item .ui-menu-item-wrapper:hover
{
    border: none !important;
    background-color: black;
}
```

could you please help me

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the following: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-classes

Comment: yes, but didn´t work

Comment: This could be due to a lack of CSS being included. Or there is some other styling that is overriding your autocomplete theming. It looks like your example code is not complete.